# How to get JSON values from angular to MongoDB

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

My controller gets data from different partials and then assemble them all in single json. After that I want to save details of that json in mongodb. How to do so?

Working Code Sample:

```
   $scope.dataIS = [
    {comm:'comm1', property_name:'property_name1', property_value:$scope.pageData.valA},
    {comm:'comm2', property_name:'property_name2', property_value:$scope.pageData.valB}
   ];
  $scope.dataValue=$scope.dataIS;
  $scope.$watch('dataValue', function(Value_JSON){
    angular.toJson(Value_JSON);
  }
```

Now I want to pull this JSON values and save it to MongoDB. I have a nodeJS server.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup an api on your node server using express (http://expressjs.com/)
then recieve the Json with bodyparser and send it to your mongodb server using an mongodb driver/mapper (https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/)

To send the JSON from Angular to your Node API check out (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)